Explosions in high viscosity liquids
I was watching The Score (2001) in which De Niro manages to make a hole in a cobalt and titanium infused steel safe. he fills it with water. inserts an explosive and boom! the safe is open.
It made me think what would have happened if instead of water the safe was filled with any other substance with higher viscosity than water. maybe runny cement or anything he could have come up with.

Would the explosion sound be less or more?

Since higher
viscosity means air molecules have a harder time expanding, how
would the explosion act differently?

Wouldn't it have been more
plausible for him to use his torch or thermite to heat the safe and
then use the water to cool it and make it brittle?



This is a good project to conduct experiment with explosion of the box filled with different substances. :)

In the limit of extremely high viscosity, the liquid is rigid.  What does that tell you?

Compressibility is more relevant than viscosity here.

Also density is important.

@AlexTrounev I emailed Ordnance Lab about it. They are a you tube channel based in Texas. They have the proper space for doing the experiment. I let everybody know their answer. In case they don't write back or you wanted to do it yourself, please be very very careful and keep in mind that different main charges work with different initiators, different initiators work with different methods like sparks, electricity, heat, physical strike...

@Blake There are two different problems here. One of them is related to the strength of the safe. And the other one is related to the method of explosive loading.
